# subequations - alignment of split environment

Tags: align, subequations, split

I want my equations to be aligned to the left by the leftmost letter, not by `=`. The following code aligns the equations by `=`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:a}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:b}
        \begin{split}
            F &= ma\\
            &= m \ddot{x}
        \end{split}\\
        \label{eq:c}
        \begin{split}
            f(x,y) &= c\\
            &= d
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried the code:

```
% my approach
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:a}
    \begin{align}
        \label{eq:b}
        \begin{split}
            &F \begin{array}[t]{ll}&= ma\\
            &= m \ddot{x}\end{array}
        \end{split}\\
        \label{eq:c}
        \begin{split}
            &f(x,y) \begin{array}[t]{ll}&= c\\
            &= d\end{array}
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

But the code looks somewhat complicated and the result is not so good; the spaces between the first letter and `=` are too large. What's the simplest solution for this?

[image]

Comment: it seems you don't want alignment at all and simply use `gather` with `\usepackage[fleeqn]{amsmath}` to get the equations flush left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve your formatting goal by using `aligned[t]` environments instead of `array` environments. (Well, one *could* achieve the same result with `array` environments, but one would also have to fiddle with the values of `\arraycolsep` and `\arraystretch`...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:a}
\begin{align} 
  \label{eq:b}
      &\begin{aligned}
          F &= ma\\
            &= m\ddot{x}
        \end{aligned}\\[\jot]
  \label{eq:c}
      &\begin{aligned}
          f(x,y) &= c\\
                 &= d
        \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```